# Sorting by price when using associative array to define custom fields

Tags: php, wordpress

I am just trying to get my posts to sort by price. I think it is causing me problems becuase I am using a associative array for my custom fields...

Also, ever since adding the query (`$posts = get_posts...`) to the top of my loop I still see the posts on the page but they have no content any more. If I delete the query the content comes back.  I just find this odd because it still know that there are 5 posts and shows spots were they should be.

My custom post type is called: `listings`

Here is my loop / query code:

```
<?php

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type'         => 'listings',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'meta_key'          => 'price',
    'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'DESC'
));

while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
endwhile;
else :
    get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
endif;
?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); // reset the query ?>
```

Here is the code used to create my custom fields:

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID,'_listing_meta',TRUE); 
?>
<p><label>City:</label><input name="listing_meta[city]" value="<?php echo $meta['city']; ?>" /></p>
<p><label>Area/Region:</label><input name="listing_meta[region]" value="<?php echo $meta['region']; ?>" /></p>
<p><label>Price:</label><input name="listing_meta[price]" value="<?php echo $meta['price']; ?>" /></p>
<p><label>MLS#:</label><input name="listing_meta[mls]" value="<?php echo $meta['mls']; ?>" /></p>
<?php
```

Comment: You can't access the individual array elements of a meta value array during WP_Query. You'll likely have to assign these meta values to individual array keys.

Comment: How would I do that?